# Как заблокировать пользователя вошедшего в программу?

Tags: c++builder, ms-access

Есть программа,работает на базе access. Кто может подсказать как правильно заблокировать пользователя который вошел, что бы следующий пользователь не мог зайти под той же учеткой?

Answer (score 1):

Вести прямо в базе таблицу логинов
логин, время логина, статус

если логин есть, если статус "вошел" и время логина меньше часа назад - то пользователь залогинен.

При выходе из программы менять статус на "вышел"

Зачем время логина - если аварийное завершение программы и юзер не пометился вышедшим - чтобы всё же можно было зайти.